# Importing users from csv file - not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import users from a csv file and currently get an error. The error i get is "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'" Provide an argument that is not null or empty"

```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the path to your CSV file"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "TESTpassw0rd!" -AsPlainText -Force

$users = Import-Csv $filepath

ForEach ($user in $users) {

$fnavn = $user."Fornavn"
$enavn = $user."Etternavn"
$ansattId = $user."AnsattID"
$OUpath = $user."Oorganizational Unit"

New-ADUser -Name "$fnavn $enavn" -GivenName $fnavn -Surname $enavn -UserPrincipalName "$fnavn.$enavn" -Path $OUpath -AccountPassword $securePassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -AnsattID $ansattId -Enabled $True


echo "Account created for $fnavn $enavn in $OUpath"

}
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't enter file path and just pressed enter.

Comment: I noticed that you've not marked any answer as accepted ever and also you've never upvoted any answer. It seems you need to take a [tour].

Comment: I tried entering the file path, after that i got the error. Seems like the problem is in the powershell script

Comment: `$OUPath` is apparently empty, write it out before you create the `New-ADUser` with something like: `Write-Host $OUPath`

Comment: I tried with the write-host $OUPath, but still get an error: "Cannot validate argument on parameter Path"